# Auto detect python 3 files in vim

Tags: regex, python-3.x, vim

I have various python plugins which use external commands such as `pydoc`.  I would like to be able to set all the appropriate commands to their python 3 counterparts, which would require some form of python 3 auto detection.  I'm not sure whether this can be done reliably, since there aren't many distinguishing factors between python 2/3.   In the end, I would want a function which looks like this:

```
function! IsPythonThree()
    ... code for detection goes here ...
    return result
endfunction
```

The only way I could see this being done is throught some regex wizardry that I have no clue how to use.

Comment: Have you considered using a python 3 hashbang to differentiate? Something like `/usr/bin/env python3`

Comment: I had considered that as an option, and it would work for a lot of python files.  However, if you are in a module which isn't meant to be directly executed from the command line, it would have no need for the shebang.

Comment: What about virtualenv to manage all your python tools?

Comment: I never have used virtualenv before, but it seems that I should learn how to use it.  That way I could just look inside the virtual environment to see which python interpreter is in use.

Comment: Another option which I use for similar issues is having a .vimrc per project. That helps a lot, or allows me to have a vim history per project.

Comment: That is true, just ad it to your ignored files in whatever version manager is being used.

Comment: Depending on your code project, vim's `modeline`'s may also work.  The downfall of that is implementing/including them in each and every file, and being the only developer, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is is significant overlap between Python 2 and 3, especially if you take `from __future__ import ...`  into account. How do you want to handle such code? As Python 2 or 3?

So I don't think you'll be able to write a 100% foolproof test.

One possible way is to execute the code with python2 using the `-3` option. This will test for incompatibilities that cannot be fixed by `2to3`. If those are found, it is definitely python 2 code.

Another is to execute the file with both python 2 and 3 and check if *only one of them* returns an error.